# AWS describe-instance-status narrowing down results (excluding returned info)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running an AWS CLI command to return all instances with a scheduled event. However, after scheduled events have been performed they still hang around for up to a week. I want to exclude completed events from my query. Here is the command I am running:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --include-all-instances --filters "Name=event.code,Values=*" --output text --query 'InstanceStatuses[].[InstanceId,Events]'
```

Currently, this returns two results with one of the events listed already complete. Is there a way to exclude the 'completed' result - like a 'does not equal' statement?

Comment: Solving a different problem... you can simply make the maintenance events go away immediately, before the scheduled event (or after, now that you mention it) by stopping and restarting the impacted instance.  That's my standard procedure.  Stop/Start on an instance will move it to new hardware, and doing it now (or sooner) rather than later allows you to control the potential disruption. Anecdotally, I've never seen one come back up on new hardware with another maintenance event pending.  That's possible, but seems extremely unlikely.

Comment: Also note that [some types of maintenance events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-instances-status-check_sched.html#types-of-scheduled-events) *require* you to do this, or your instance will simply stop on its own and not come back without intervention.  The more that I think about it, a maintenance event in the past means there is something you did not handle proactively.